# Change the font size of a unicode character in my bash prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, fonts, prompt

I've implemented a custom bash prompt by exporting PS1 in my .bashrc, but I'm using a unicode character that appears very small unless the font size is changed.  Unfortunately that means text looks ridiculous.  Is there a way to change only the font size of that single character to a larger one so as to make it more clearly visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no escape code for text size ([source](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes)). Therefore, there's no way to resize a single character in terminal.

Your best bet will be to look through Unicode and find a larger version of the same character. Or you could make the character bold.

Comment: Thank you.  This seems to be in line with what my research says, but gives me a definitive answer.