# How to change the font size of just the prompt in bash?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fonts, bashrc, ps1

I would like to be able to identify the prompt (`username@PCname`) easily in a bunch of text.

I know the color of it can be changed and also the prompt can be edited to show what we want. But how do I change the font size of just the prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the font size of a unicode character in my bash prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806817/change-the-font-size-of-a-unicode-character-in-my-bash-prompt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's something not possible to achieve. The prompt and output text are technically same object. The text isn't located in separate buttons/window object to set different font for each.

As alternative, consider doing the following:

- use [control sequences](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html) to make it highlight or appear bold.
- use all-caps prompt.
- [spread the prompt into several lines](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html)

Comment: Hello I was able to make it bold by adding the corresponding escape sequence to PS1. But I am not sure how to highlight and set all caps. Can you please expand?

Comment: @code_brah  simply set `PS1="USER@HOST: $ "`. See? I didn't do anything special except put stuff in all caps by hand. You can write commands to do that , but the easiest path is via editing by hand.

Comment: Oh that was too simple. Also, in the comments section here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html#comment-170405, 
A guy named Cody says this: "Firstly, look in /lib/kbd/consolefonts Next, look at setfont(8) You can use it like: setfont -C $(tty) Lastly if that is one you like, then set SYSFONT to that (minus the extension of .psfu.gz) in /etc/sysconfig/i18n"         I do not understand what this means. Does it mean the font size can be changed?        Thanks

Comment: Yes, he means that it's possible to change fonts like this, but there's no `/lib/kbd/consolefonts` directory in ( at least mine ) Ubuntu, but they're talking about CentOS, so it might work for that OS. Font and font size changing for GUI terminals can be done from terminal's setting, that's it - there's nothing special to do. For TTY console there is different way, I think via `sudo dpkg --reconfigure console-setup`.

Comment: I just came to know that we can also set background color for the prompt so that it stands out. Just wanted to add to the answer.